# Datediff for mysql subquery multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in following structures. I want to calculate **Total_days** using each start_date & end_date against each emp_id. For all empty End_date, current date need to be used.

I know DATEDIFF, CURDATE() function will be used along with some kind of loop but don't know how to use it to accomplish desired output.

I was searching for loops in subquery in MYSQL but unfortunately in some answered questions in SO it was mentioned that there are no loops only sets. Hence not posting my version of query here.

**Table 1**

```
emp_id  emp_name
1       AAA
2       BBB
3       CCC
```

**Table 2**

```
emp_id  Start_date   End_date
1       05-FEB-2014  
1       01-SEP-2012  04-FEB-2014
1       01-OCT-2010  31-AUG-2012
2       13-JAN-2010  28-SEP-2014
2       29-SEP-2014  31-DEC-2018
```

**OUTPUT EXPECTED**

```
emp_id  emp_name     Total_days
1       AAA          3030
2       BBB          3273
3       CCC          0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to compute the sum of the days difference between start and end date, over all records related to each employee.

You indeed could use an aggregate query with [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) and COALESCE :

```
SELECT 
    t1.emp_id,
    t1.emp_name,
    SUM(
        COALESCE(
            DATEDIFF(
                COALESCE(t2.end_date, CURDATE()),
                t2.start_date
            ),
        0
    ) as total_days
FROM
    table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
       ON t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
GROUP BY 
    t1.emp_id,
    t1.emp_name
```

The LEFT JOIN avoids filtering out records that cannot be matched in table2. DATEDIFF returns the number of days between two dates. If any of the dates is NULL, it returns NULL. You can pick that up with COALESCE and return 0 instead.

Comment: Thanks @GMB, though i was going to figure out CURDATE() part myself but at the very same moment you shared edited version which saved my time. Thank you. This worked perfectly!

Comment: Welcome @techworld !

Answer (score 0):

You can use Group By for inner query and then `DATEDIFF`

```
SELECT 
  Table1.EMP_ID, 
  Table1.EMP_NAME, 
  COALESCE(DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date),0) diff
FROM
(
   SELECT EMP_ID, MIN(START_DATE) START_DATE, MAX(END_DATE) END_DATE 
   FROM Table2
   GROUP By emp_ID
) t
RIGHT JOIN Table1 ON Table1.emp_id = t.emp_id
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43099517fb3a5ec92ed2a6a64c608219)